# Increment a list based on digits in a number (Python)

Tags: python

(this is long and maybe confusing) I am currently working on a small project that involves analysing ballot papers and determining the winning candidate based on the number of votes they receive. The voting system used is very unusual. For example, if there are four candidates the vote could look like this: 3241 (3 points for the first candidate, 2 points for the second candidate etc). To determine the winner I have to add up all of the votes for each candidate. For example, if the 3 ballots were [1342, 3241, 3214] the amount of points for the first candidate would be 1+3+3 = 7 (Lower the better). If every candidate has a different number of points, declaring the winner is simple. However, I am having a lot of trouble declaring the winner when there is a tie. For example, the final score would be [7,7,9,7]. To declare the winner if there is a tie I need to look at the preference order of the votes (basically check how many 1's each candidate got, how many 2's each candidate got etc) and store them in a list which look something like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The list for the example above would look like this when finished:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1]]
```

Meaning candidate 4 would win has they have the most second preference votes out of everyone who received first preference votes. The method that I am currently trying to implement simply doesn't work and uses a lot of if statements:

```
for i in range(candidateNumberInt*len(voteList)):
            vote = voteList[0][i]
            if i == 0 and vote == 1:
                drawList[0][i] += 1 # This is the list with the zeros
```

The above code snippet would be the way that I would implement this (with 12 more if statements).

Edit (Thank you to responders):

```
for votes in voteList:
            for i, vote in enumerate(votes):
                print(int(vote))
                drawList[i][i] += 1
```

I have added the code above yet it outputting the just '3' in every list:

```
[[3, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3]]
```

I am just wondering if there is an easier way to increment elements in these lists based on the digits in the votes.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you need to do here is you need to create another index that will map each possible voting score into its count for each candidate id. This will allow you to iterate over the scores and check who got the most 1s, then if there's a tie who got most 2s and so on...

Comment: Suppose that the main array is called `ballots`, then you can do something like `for ballot in ballots:  for cand_id, vote in enumerate(ballot): vote_to_candidate[vote][cand_id] += 1`. Didn't include here all the initializations. When the `vote_to_candidate` index is ready, check who got most of the 1s and if there's a tie, proceed to 2, and so on

Comment: If this is a project that might be added to later (as opposed to throw away code), then it may save you more trouble later to take the time to define a class for each ballot paper. Thus instead of dealing with ints like `3214` you can deal with objects which have attributes and methods that make the analysis easier. Just one of the ways that harder problems with too much going on can be divided into multiple simple problems.